# Correctly file income from NSOs as non-resident citizen

Tags: united-states, income-tax, employee-stock-options, foreign-income

I'm a **dual citizen** (Belgium - USA) and have lived / worked in Belgium always.

Because I pay taxes in Belgium, I've been using the **Foreign Earned Income Exclusion** (FEIE) to offset my wages and paying $0 tax until now.

My only source of income at this moment is wages as employee in a company.

I have been granted **Non-qualified Stock Options** (NSOs) by my employer, and want to figure out how to correctly file these at the moment I exercise and sell.

From what I understand, there are multiple options: exercise and sell later or exercise and sell same day. I'm mainly interested in the latter case, but comments on the former can be interesting.

Say my yearly income is $40k, and in the same year I **exercise and sell** the options (same day) for a total gain of $100k, what would be the proper way to file this?

I read that these are **not capital gains**, but seen as actual income / wage, so I assume they can be offset by the FEIE also.

However, I don't understand if the $100k + $40k end up in the **same year**, and will thus be larger than the FEIE (e.g. ~$108k in 2021).

Or am I allowed to **spread** the $100k income over the vesting period, and thus "go backwards in time" with filing, ending up under the FEIE per year, and not be double-taxed on these?

So my questions:

- Can I actually offset the NSO income by the FEIE?
- Can I spread the NSO income over the vesting period, so I end up offsetting all of the income (no double taxation)?
- If I can spread this out, what does filing look like? Do I amend previous years?
- Anything else important I should know?